# Using module from lib.rs by doing use crate::module

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use, in `client.rs`, pub functions defined in `parser_utilities.rs`

project:

```
src/client.rs
src/lib.rs
src/parser_utilities.rs
```

client.rs:

```
use crate::parser_utilities::{parse_c_seq, parse_session};
```

lib.rs:

```
pub mod parser_utilities;
```

parser_utilities.rs:

```
pub fn parse_c_seq...
pub fn parse_session...
```

Error:

```
 --> src/client.rs:2:12
  |
2 | use crate::parser_utilities::{parse_c_seq, parse_session};
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |            |
  |            unresolved import
  |            help: a similar path exists: `rtsp_client::parser_utilities`
```

I then try:

client.rs:

```
use rtsp_client::parser_utilities::{parse_c_seq, parse_session};

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `rtsp_client`
 --> src/client.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use rtsp_client::parser_utilities::{parse_c_seq, parse_session};
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `rtsp_client`
```

but my crate is called `rtsp_client`

I also tried `crate::rtsp_client::parser_utilities`

What is wrong? I should be able to access any pub module from `lib.rs` using `use crate mod_name;`

Comment: Have you added `mod client` in lib.rs?

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix yes